# Tried to write an Object Oriented Python program to calculate volume of cylinder

Tags: python, oop

I tried to write an OOPS python program to calculate the volume of cylinder but when I run my code I get"Process returned 0". I need to define class "Cylinder", take input from the user. Below is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
from math import pi


# FUNCTIONS
def cylinder_volume(radius, height):
    return ((pi * (radius ** 2))*height)


# main
def Cylinder():
    radius = float(input("Radius="))
    height = float(input("Height="))

    print("Cylinder volume: %d" % (cylinder_volume(radius, height)))

# PROGRAM RUN
    if __name__ == "__Cylinder__":
        Cylinder()
```

Comment: You did not define a class `Cylinder`.  You defined a function.  Classes start with `class`.

Comment: The "Process returned 0" happened because (a) you have the indentation wrong on the last two lines, so those are actually part of the function; thus, there was no code to execute, and (b) once you fixed that, it still wouldn't run because the `__name__` variable has the value `"__main__"`, not `"__Cylinder__"`.

Comment: Do not change the functionality of the code in your post, because that makes the comments and answers nonsensical. You also removed the actual calculation. I rolled it back for you.

Comment: Honestly, you're doing a lot of things wrong. Have you learned OOP, and do you know how to define classes? Do you know [the purpose of `if __name__ == "__main__":`](/q/419163/4518341)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you would do that in a object-oriented way.  You define a Cylinder object, which owns the radius and the height.  It's up to the caller to do the I/O; the object only holds the state and has methods.  Then, the object has a `volume` method that returns the cylinder volume.

And the `__name__` variable when you run a Python script is always `"__main__"`.

```
import math

class Cylinder():
    def __init__(self, radius, height):
        self.radius = radius
        self.height = height

    def getVolume(self):
        return math.pi * (self.radius ** 2) * self.height

if __name__ == "__main__":
    radius = float(input("Radius="))
    height = float(input("Height="))
    cyl = Cylinder(radius, height)
    print("Cylinder volume:", cyl.getVolume())
```

Comment: You need `self.radius` and `self.height` for `volume`